# Can't get Craft running on Heroku

Tags: server, apache, logs

I'm familiar with Heroku, but new to Craft CMS. 
In order to get a site running, I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@aj1215/craft-cms-on-heroku-79b991665b0b#.8b561b1b4

But the site isn't functioning. My Heroku app just results in: `Application Error An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.`

My development server runs fine. But I have no idea what I need to do to get the heroku app to function. I'm pulling my hair out.

I've tried everything I can think of, but can't get it to work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

These are messages toward the end of my Heroku logs:

```
2016–01–31T03:09:21.480751+00:00 app[web.1]: nginx: [emerg] “server” directive is not allowed here in /app/nginx_app.conf:1
2016–01–31T03:09:21.475721+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting nginx…
2016–01–31T03:09:21.481090+00:00 app[web.1]: Process exited unexpectedly: nginx
2016–01–31T03:09:21.481236+00:00 app[web.1]: Going down, terminating child processes…
2016–01–31T03:09:22.183035+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016–01–31T03:09:22.182791+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016–01–31T03:09:27.185620+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc=”App crashed” method=GET path=”/” host=paradata.herokuapp.com request_id=1e502143–94ac-4aea-b34b-3087addd1d20 fwd=”172.11.56.78" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

enginx_app.conf file:

```
        location / {
            # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
            try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
        }
        location @rewriteapp {
            # rewrite all to index.php
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?p=$1 last;
        }
        location ~ ^/(index)\.php(/|$) {
            client_max_body_size 20M;
            fastcgi_pass heroku-fcgi;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        }
```

this is my `craft/config/db.php` file:

```
<?php

$url = parse_url(getenv("CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL"));

return array(

    'server' => $url["host"],

    'user' => $url["user"],

    'password' => $url["pass"],

    'database' => substr($url["path"],1),

    'tablePrefix' => 'craft',

);
```

Comment: Sounds like something is messed up in your nginx conf file.  Can you share it?

Comment: @BradBell Thank you, Brad. Yes, I'll put that code in immediately.

Comment: I'm no nginx expert, but I'm pretty sure the `server` block goes in the `http` block and not the other way around: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/

Comment: @BradBell Thanks. i removed the SERVER and HTML calls in the nginx and now the error is "Craft can’t connect to the database with the credentials in craft/config/db.php." when I try to visit /admin. I'll post my db.php if it helps. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you! @BradBell It just started working for some reason. I really just added spaces between some lines in my db.php and that was it. :/

Comment: Hah... maybe some weird caching issue going on.  Anyway, glad you're up and running!  Would you mind summarizing what got you going and adding it as an official answer?

Comment: @BradBell Thanks again. I added the answer. However, I have one more 'easy' question for you: Images in my public/images folder are not making it to heroku. Where should I be putting those instead? Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.

I needed to remove calls to 'server' and 'http' in my enginx_app.conf file. Now the file only makes calls to 'location'.

Comment: How'd you get the permissions for /app/craft/storage sorted?